# how can I declare multiple bools as false

Tags: c#, .net

Instead of declaring:

```
bool one = false;
bool two = false;
bool three = false;
```

Is it possible to declare something like:

```
bool one, two, three;
```

while setting them all to `false` ?

```
bool one, two, three = false
```

Comment: if you wanna make sure, that they are set to false, even if they have been set to true elsewhere - create an array of all bools, and set them to false through a foreach loop.

Answer (score 8):

> The default value of a bool variable is false. The default value of a bool? variable is null.

For reference you can visit: [bool (C# Reference).](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/bool)

But you cannot use it unless `assigned` with values.

```
bool one, two, three;
one = two = three = false
```

The same goes with nullable boolean:

```
bool? isCase = null;
if (isCase.HasValue){
    //TODO:
   }
```

Comment: That doesn't spare you assigning them if you ever want to use them. At least *my* compiler complains about *Use of unassigned variable ...*.

Comment: Thanks, I just quote it from Microsoft Docs. I completed my explanation with codes for better understanding. @Filburt

Answer (score 4):

You could either do:

```
bool one = false, two = false, three = false
```

Or

```
bool one, two, three;
one = two = three = false;
```

Answer (score 3):

bools are false by default.

so

```
bool one, two, three;
```

Gives you three bools set to false. BUT - when you try to use them you'll get an error, eg:

> Use of unassigned local variable 'three'

You need to initialise them before you use them:

```
bool one = false, two = false,three = false;
```

Comment: ahh ok nice one man thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in syntax to do that. And though `bool`s have default value of `false`, C# requires you to initialze variables before you use them.

The only way I cant think of that may help you is to declare an array:

```
bool[] bools = new bool[3];
Console.WriteLine(bools[0]);
Console.WriteLine(bools[1]);
Console.WriteLine(bools[2]);
```

The array is initialized with `false` values, but you loose the semantics of your variable names (so I actually prefer [Ashkan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45976567/5528593)'s answer).

Answer (score 1):

2 Shorter ways to do that would be:

```
bool one = false, two = false, three = false;
```

Or:

```
bool one, two, three;
one = two = three = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

go like this:

```
bool one, two;
one = two = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

simply, just like this:

```
one = two = three = false
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are too many put them in an array and use loop.
Otherwise, I think this works fine.

```
bool one, two, three;
one = two = three = false;
```